# C programming pointers and arrays

Tags: c

```
void main(){
    char *const p="Hello";
    p++;   // causes error object p non modifiable 
}

void main(){
    char A[10]="ANSHU";
    A++;  // here causes lvalue problem  
}
```

So, my question is, what is difference between these two programs and next question is that is array's declaration like this

```
int *const A;
```

Comment: You really need to learn basics before hitting the code

Comment: It would be good to re-edit the question, so the meta text "enter code here" disappears and the two code blocks stand as they should ;-) ... and please only one question per question ... it reads a bit like any C (pointer) tutorial out there or existing SO answers already should help ...

Comment: You can click the [edit] button to finish up your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `char *const p="Hello";` `p` is a `const pointer` to a (non-const) `char`. You can change the actual char, but not the pointer pointing to it. So, **It cannot point to any other memory location after its initialization.** Its important to note that in this statement, the initialization has to be done when declaring this pointer.

In `char A[10]="ANSHU";` `A` is an array object and not a `pointer`. so you could not use the operation `A++` for an array object.

In `int *const A;` **`A` is a const pointer to int**. So, Pointer cannot change, pointed to value can change.

Answer (score 1):

In the first program you declared `p` as `const`, regardless of its type. So you cannot assign to it after the first initialization. `p++` tries to assign to `p` the value of `p+1` and thus fails.

In the second program you used an array. The name of the array, `A` is actually like a **label**. You can use it as an address to pass on, but you can't change it.